# how do I find a particular class of the closest element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a particular class match from a closest element

```
     $(this).closest("tr");
```

I need to find out if this tr has a class name testlog3 from the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the closest function as follows:

```
$(this).closest('tr.testlog3');
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?... if you want to make sure the selector found something, check it's length: `$(this).closest('tr.testlog3').length` otherwise please share some HTML and/or what you are trying to do with the table row.

Comment: Sorry Mottie, your solution did work and like working with length instead. I did it wrong as in: if($(this).closest("tr.logtest3").length > 1)

Comment: I should have put: if($(this).closest("tr.logtest3").length >= 1)

Comment: You can simplify that even more: `if ($(this).closest('tr.logtest3').length) { /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass):

```
if($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('testlog3')) {
    // ...
```